# Babel 6 preset selection to get babel working

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs, ecmascript-2016

I'm using babel 6 with the react plugin and followed the documentation instructions for setting up the transpile process. I've read to get react working I need to use `es2015` and react `preset`. Initially everything worked fine using this both presets.

But when I've copied an example code from babel's [website](http://babeljs.io/blog/2015/06/07/react-on-es6-plus/) (Property initializers)
 to test new language features I've got errors when code below was transpiled and so it wasn't possible anymore to transpile the code.

```
// The ES6+ way
class Video extends React.Component {
    static defaultProps^= { // this is line 42 and ^ the column where error occurs
        autoPlay: false,
        maxLoops: 10,
    }

    static propTypes = {
        autoPlay: React.PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
        maxLoops: React.PropTypes.number.isRequired,
        posterFrameSrc: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired,
        videoSrc: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    }

    state = {
        loopsRemaining: this.props.maxLoops,
    }
}
```

`Warning: [...]components/sectorList.js: Unexpected token (42:24) Use --force to continue.`

After a long while debuggin I've got this issue solved by loading also the `stage-0` preset for babel. But it was just luck.

So my question where I can't find an answer for is:

**How is the correct way to determine the correct preset collection.**

Or is an unexpected token ... warning mostly a notification for an missing preset?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the babel pages for a preset, it lists all the included transformations. In this case, you're using class properties, which is currently at stage 1 and is therefore included in the [stage 1 preset](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-stage-1).

In ES2015, you'd use the constructor to set the defaults.

Comment: Ok so what I've done using stage-0 beside es-2015 can be transpiled using the preset but isn't valid? More a mix from different standards?

Comment: es2015 is the 'next' standard, with the major browsers supporting about 80% right now. stage-0 (-1, -2, -3) are collections of proposals for the future development. I believe it takes about two years from stage-0 to an agreed-upon standard. So es2015 and stage-0 aren't contradictory.

Comment: Thanks for your comment really helped me very much to understand better how babel works.